# How to remove many elements from the list by checking it's index in Maxima CAS?

Tags: list, maxima

I use Maxima CAS to create the list:

```
a:makelist(i,i,1,20);
```

result:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I want to slim the list and leave only every third element. To find it I check index i of the list a :

```
mod(i,3)>0
```

to find elements.

My code :

```
l:length(a);
for i:1 thru l step 1 do if (mod(i,3)>0) then a:delete(a[i],a);
```

Of course it does not work because length of a is changing.

I can do it using second list:

```
b:[];
for i:1 thru l step 1 do if (mod(i,3)=0) then b:cons(a[i],b);
```

Is it the best method ?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to solve this, as know already. My advice is to construct a list of the indices you want to keep, and then construct the list of elements from that. E.g.:

```
(%i1) a:makelist(i,i,1,20);
(%o1) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
(%i2) ii : sublist (a, lambda ([a1], mod(a1, 3) = 0));
(%o2)                  [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
(%i3) makelist (a[i], i, ii);
(%o3)                  [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

The key part is the last step, `makelist(a[i], i, ii)`, where `ii` is the list of indices you want to select. `ii` might be constructed in various ways. Here is a different way to construct the list of indices:

```
(%i4) ii : makelist (3*i, i, 1, 6);
(%o4)                  [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way (I do not know which one is best or faster) with compact code: `makelist(a[3*i],i,1,length(a)/3)`
Test example:

```
l1:makelist(i,i,1,12)$
l2:makelist(i,i,1,14)$
l3:[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]$
for a in [l1,l2,l3] do (
    b:makelist(a[3*i],i,1,length(a)/3),
    print(a,"=>",b)
)$
```

Result:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] => [3,6,9,12]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] => [3,6,9,12]

[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29] => [5,13,23]